# Can't get property if they are an object using linq to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using Linq to SQL and I have the following query :

```
 var query = from P in _dbContext.Clients
             join C in _dbContext.Contacts on P.Idclient equals C.Idclient
             where P.Idclient == identifier
             select P;

 client = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

There is the model "Client" :

```
public int Idclient { get; set; }

public string Nomclient { get; set; } = null!;

public string? Adresse { get; set; }

public string? Ville { get; set; }

public string? Codepostal { get; set; }

public string? Numtel { get; set; }

public string? Saisielibre { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
```

I have a list of "Contact" into a client but in the result of my query, my contact are not here and I don't know how to put them into the property "Contacts" of a client.

Thank's for your help

Comment: Is the list property NULL?  Did the model change?  If model changed, did you do a migration?  Do database contains the contacts?  How did you add the contacts to the database?

Comment: You should avoid trying to use `join`s in Entity Framework queries, instead rely on the navigation properties. So you can instead do something simple like `client = _dbContext.Clients(c => c.Idclient == identifier).Include(c => c.Contacts).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Just put Include after `_dbContext.Clients` - `from P in _dbContext.Clients.Include(c => c.Contacts) from ...`